# Как добавить функцию очистки input с помощью JS?

Tags: javascript, input

Есть готовая форма в стиле Material Design

Пытаюсь добавить кнопки сброса к инпутам в виде крестиков, появляющихся справа когда в поле есть значение.

Подскажите как добавить событие на кнопку (крестик), чтобы при нажатии на неё поле очищалось?

```js
const setActive = (el, active) => {
  const formField = el.parentNode.parentNode;
  if (active) {
   formField.classList.add('form-field--is-active');
    el.value === '' ?
    formField.classList.remove('form-field--is-clear') :
    formField.classList.add('form-field--is-clear');
  } else {
    formField.classList.remove('form-field--is-clear');
    formField.classList.remove('form-field--is-active');
    el.value === '' ?
    formField.classList.remove('form-field--is-filled') :
    formField.classList.add('form-field--is-filled');
  }
};



[].forEach.call(
document.querySelectorAll('.form-field__input, .form-field__textarea'),
el => {
  el.onblur = () => {
    setActive(el, false);
  };
  el.onfocus = () => {
    setActive(el, true);
  };

 el.onkeyup = () => {
    setActive(el, true);
  };

});
```

```css
.form-field {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  width:300px;
}

.form-field--is-active .form-field__control:before {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #0088cc, inset 0 0 0 1px #0088cc!important;
  
}


.form-field--is-active .form-field__label {
  font-size: 12px;
  transform: translateY(-13px);
}
.form-field--is-filled .form-field__label {
  font-size: 12px;
  transform: translateY(-13px);
}



.form-field__label {
  display: block;
  color: #878787;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 12px 18px;
  line-height: 22px;
}

.form-field__control {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.form-field__control:before {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #ccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    content: "";
    z-index: 0;
    border-radius: 4px;
    transition: .1s ease-out;
    transition-property: border;
}

.form-field:hover .form-field__control:before {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #878787;
}

.has-error .form-field__control:before {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #f73d34!important;
}

.form-field__input,
.form-field__textarea {
    padding: 20px 12px 18px;
    font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 22px;
    display: block;
  background: none;
  border: 0;
   transition: .1s ease-out;
    transition-property: color;
 
  margin: 0;
  
  
  width: 100%;
  
  position: relative;
    
}

.form-field--is-filled .form-field__input, .form-field--is-active .form-field__input, .form-field--is-filled .form-field__textarea, .form-field--is-active .form-field__textarea {
    padding-top: 28px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.form-field__input:focus,
.form-field__textarea:focus {
    
outline: 0; 
}


.form-field__clear {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
 opacity: .2;
    z-index: 1;
  border: 0;
  display: none;
  padding: 0 10px;
  font-weight: 400;
 transition: opacity .1s ease-out;
 background: transparent;
  outline: none;
  font-size:20px;
}

.form-field__clear:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.form-field--is-clear .form-field__clear {
 
  display: block;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="form-field">
 <div class="form-field__control">
     <label class="form-field__label">Имя</label>

<button type="button" class="form-field__clear" >&times;</button>
        <input  class="form-field__input" type="text">
   </div>
   </div>

<div class="form-field">
 <div class="form-field__control">
     <label class="form-field__label">Фамилия</label>

<button type="button" class="form-field__clear" >&times;</button>
        <input  class="form-field__input" type="text">
   </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.form-field__clear'), (button) => {
  const field = button.parentNode.querySelector('.form-field__input');
  button.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    field.value = '';
  });
});
```

Comment: К сожалению не сработало https://codepen.io/mx928/pen/JjbBYMV

Comment: Поправил, попробуйте теперь

Comment: Спасибо, Работает! Подскажите пожалуйста как скрыть кнопку после того как форма очищена?

Comment: Также есть проблема, некоторые поля имеют значения при загрузке страницы, подскажите как сделать проверку если поле имеет значение при загрузке страницы и в этом случае присвоить клас ".form-field--is-filled"  https://codepen.io/mx928/pen/JjbBYMV

Answer (score 1):

Получился такой код, все вроде как работает как и хотелось, если есть ошибки или можно ка то оптимизировать, подскажите пожалуйста!

https://codepen.io/mx928/pen/JjbBYMV

```js
const setActive = (el, active) => {
  const formField = el.parentNode.parentNode;
  if (active) {
   formField.classList.add('form-field--is-active');
    el.value === '' ?
    formField.classList.remove('form-field--is-clear') :
    formField.classList.add('form-field--is-clear');
  } else {
    formField.classList.remove('form-field--is-clear');
    formField.classList.remove('form-field--is-active');
    el.value === '' ?
    formField.classList.remove('form-field--is-filled') :
    formField.classList.add('form-field--is-filled');
  }
};

[].forEach.call(
document.querySelectorAll('.form-field__input, .form-field__textarea'),
  
el => {
  if (el.value) {
    setActive(el, false);
   }
  el.onblur = () => {
    setActive(el, false);
  };
  el.onfocus = () => {
    setActive(el, true);
  };
 el.onkeyup = () => {
    setActive(el, true);
  };

});

[].forEach.call(
document.querySelectorAll('.form-field__clear'), 
(button) => {
  const field = button.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('.form-field__input, .form-field__textarea');
  button.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    field.value = '';
    field.parentNode.parentNode.classList.remove('form-field--is-clear');
  });
});
```